# Servlet works with old SQL data

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets

I have strange problem, I am working on web application with java servlets and SQLite, using Jquery as front end. It has been successful so far but recently when I manually delete or add something to database (from SQLite Studio), and restart the server, I still get old data, it's like new data doesn't get loaded at all, all I have is data that is actually deleted.

e.g. I had 10 movies in my database, and deleted 3 of them from SQLite Studio, but when I load application, I still get 10 movies.

Is there a way to re-initalise database? I have red something about clearing cache, but not being successful with it.

By the way, I deleted database in SQLite Studio and made new one with same name and data. Maybe that's the problem, I need somehow to re-initialise it

Here is my ConnectionManager, which has been working fine till today (been working on this application for over a month).

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cinema.db";

    private static final String FILE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    private static final String WINDOWS_PATH = "C:" + FILE_SEPARATOR + "Users" + FILE_SEPARATOR + 
            "Marnitzinho" + FILE_SEPARATOR + "Documents" + FILE_SEPARATOR + DATABASE_NAME;
    private static final String LINUX_PATH = "SQLite" + FILE_SEPARATOR + DATABASE_NAME;

    private static final String PATH = WINDOWS_PATH;

    private static Connection connection;

    public static void open() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + PATH);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static void close() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

InitListener

```
public class InitListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ConnectionManager.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Initialization....");

        ConnectionManager.open();

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>cinema.dao.InitListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here is picture of file with path and other info https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqk5r.jpg

Any kind of help is appreciated, really stuck on this.

EDIT: I made new file and connected to it but now I get,

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: movies)
```

but there is such table...

Comment: Basic question: Are you sure you committed the "manual" deletion on the query analyzer you used (SQLLite Studio, here, I guess)?

Comment: Yes I did, it seems that application has file that was deleted and doesn't load new file, I need somehow to initialise new file not old one

Comment: e.g. I delete user from SQLite Studio and when I load application, I can still log in with him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making new db file and moving it into project directory.